# How to programmatically trigger the touch event in android?

Tags: android, touch, gesture-recognition, gestures

I would like to trigger a touch event like this:

First the finger is touch down at the (0,50%) of the screen and slide to the (50%,50%) of the screen, and exit (move the finger off the screen)

I have found some thing like this:

```
MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, action, x, y, pressure, size, metaState, xPrecision, yPrecision, deviceId, edgeFlags);

onTouchEvent(event);
```

However, how to emulate the above case? Do I need to create 2 event ? onTouchDown , onMove etc.... ? Thanks for helping.

Comment: you can override http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Comment: Right now I have the function of the ontouchEvent already, and i would like to trigger it programmtically instead of the user manually touch on the screen

Comment: I have think of calling the ontouch event in a function directly but it is quite complex so I think the best way is to emulate the touch event

Answer (score 115, accepted):

```
// Obtain MotionEvent object
long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;
// List of meta states found here:     developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState()
int metaState = 0;
MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
    downTime, 
    eventTime, 
    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 
    x, 
    y, 
    metaState
);

// Dispatch touch event to view
view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
```

Comment: How should I declare and initialize the view object?

Comment: what about swipe gesture left, right, top and bottom.. using ACTION_MOVE is it possible ?

Comment: @Ramesh_D You would have to generate a lot of `ACTION_MOVE` events to simulate a swipe.

Comment: A swipe can be generated with an `ACTION_DOWN`, an `ACTION_MOVE`, and an `ACTION_UP`.

Comment: I use this, worked perfectly, onTouch event is called, but I found one issue when i use above code and hold my finger on the view and move, ontouchevent  not called

Comment: what's the view definition?

Answer (score 6):

And here is the clean version:

```
public void TouchView(View view)
{
    view.DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.Obtain(SystemClock.UptimeMillis(), SystemClock.UptimeMillis(), (int)MotionEventActions.Down, 0, 0, 0));
    view.DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.Obtain(SystemClock.UptimeMillis(), SystemClock.UptimeMillis(), (int)MotionEventActions.Up, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

PS: This is a xamarin android solution but you can easily modify it for java

Answer (score 1):

To add to the excellent answer by @bstar55 above - if what you want is to create a 'tap' event, e.g, a user tapping on a view, then you need to simulate the user touching the screen and then removing their finger in a short time frame.

To do this you 'dispatch' an ACTION_DOWN MotionEvent followed after a short time by an ACTION_UP MotionEvent.

The following example, in Kotlin, is tested and worked reliably:

```js
   //Create amd send a tap event at the current target loctaion to the PhotoView
   //From testing (on an original Google Pixel) a tap event needs an ACTION_DOWN followed shortly afterwards by
   //an ACTION_UP, so send both events
   //First, create amd send the ACTION_DOWN MotionEvent
   var originalDownTime: Long = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
   var eventTime: Long = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100
   var x = your_X_Value
   var y = your_Y_Value 
   var metaState = 0
   var motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
           originalDownTime,
           eventTime,
           MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
           x,
           y,
           metaState
    )
    var returnVal = yourView.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent)
    Log.d(TAG,"rteurnVal: " + returnVal)

    //Create amd send the ACTION_UP MotionEvent
    eventTime= SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100
    motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
           originalDownTime,
           eventTime,
           MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
           x,
           y,
           metaState
     )
     returnVal = yourView.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent)
     Log.d(TAG,"rteurnVal: " + returnVal)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fun View.performTouchDown() = dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent
    .obtain(uptimeMillis(), uptimeMillis() + 700, ACTION_DOWN, 0f, 0f, 0))
```