# How to get onTouch to be called on a view behind a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, ontouchlistener

I have a view behind a `ViewPager`. This view slides up and down vertically, using an `OnTouchListener`. This works fine when part of the view is shown, but I'd like to make it so users can swipe downward from the top of the `ViewPager` to reveal this view. I've tried subclassing `ViewPager` and returning false in `onInterceptTouchEvent`, but it did not work. I've also tried adding this `OnTouchListener` to the `ViewPager` itself as a hack but this didn't work either.

The images below represent what I'm trying to achieve.

> Collapsed View behind ViewPager

[image: Collapsed View behind ViewPager]

> Swiping View from behind the ViewPager

[image: Swiping View from behind the ViewPager]

This is the simple layout code I've been testing with:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <View
          android:id="@+id/content"
          android:background="@android:color/black"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
          android:id="@+id/viewPager"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="128dp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simulating the touch event of your View on touch event of your ViewPager, follow this for simulating the touch event,
[How to programmatically trigger the touch event in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902892/how-to-programmatically-trigger-the-touch-event-in-android). 
Let me know if this works.

Comment: I basically added an `onTouchListener` to the `ViewPager` to do the exact same stuff as the view behind it. I _thought_ I did this earlier, but I actually put the `onTouchListener` on its parent view (the layout indeed is more complicated than the xml above, I just made a booboo) :/