# How to generate virtual touch on screen?

Tags: android, touch, virtual, instrumentation, floating

I want to generate a touch event via programming on the screen outside of my app. My app currently has a floating window. I am trying to make something like [repetitouch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cygery.repetitouch.pro&hl=en)
I used the [Hover](https://github.com/viorgu/Hover) library to create a floating window to display some message and buttons. I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902892/how-to-programmatically-trigger-the-touch-event-in-android) answer but the Hover library doesn't provide me with any views to work on
[ when I try to use view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent); ]
The ClassName.this, getView() and all don't work.
Is there any other floating window library which provides views after implementation so that I can generate touches via code. 
Can I do this task using services? If yes, what should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution. I used instrumentation.

```
InstrumentationObj.sendPointerSync(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x_coordinate, y_coordinate, 0));
```

Comment: Can it be also used in command line ? Because I’m not an android developer and trying to use python to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:::::**
Refer the following link that shows **How to stimulate touch event in android**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23902985/9287163

(Hope you find it useful)

Comment: I want to 'generate' touch events programmatically not 'detect' touches from user.

Comment: I don't think you've bothered to check what my question is and what the hyperlinks are for -_- The link you posted is the exact link i mentioned in the question.