# Google Maps Android API - trigger touch event on map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I need a way to trigger/fire a map touch event programmatically. Is there any solution?

**Update 1:**

I have map and a `kmlLayer` on it. the kmlLayer has only a click event but in my case I need to fire this event when I click on another button. it's exactly what I want.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23902985/3534952) I add a fake and programmatically touch event but it not worked on a map view!

**Update 2:**

My question is totally different with [Google Maps Android API v2 - detect touch on map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013002/google-maps-android-api-v2-detect-touch-on-map). Because it is about how to interact when a real touch happend but in my case I want to fire event programmaticly first! after this the map or laye listener.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps Android API v2 - detect touch on map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013002/google-maps-android-api-v2-detect-touch-on-map)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Really no!

Comment: Retracted close vote as question was improved. But you really need to put more detail into what the `kmlLayer` is doing and explain why don't you just modify the [Google Maps Utility Library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) to do what you want.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I show my support area on a map by a kmlLayer. and I want to get a kmlLayer clicked point lat lng.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this...

```
googleMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraMoveStarted(int reason) {
        if (reason == REASON_GESTURE) {
            // The user gestured on the map.
        } else if (reason == REASON_API_ANIMATION) {
            // The user tapped something on the map.
        } else if (reason == REASON_DEVELOPER_ANIMATION) {
            // The app moved the camera.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I really don't understand why the dears downvoted this question! This is not my solution! Is this question unclear?