# How to hide UI when ajust volume

Tags: android, user-interface, volume

In Android
In my app there are 2 buttons to increase and decrease volume.
my need is to show UI volume bar(the Volume level dialog in the above of the screen) when I press buttons and hide it after a while.

my problem is:

- I can ajust volume without show UI
- I can ajust volume and show UI but  then UI is on screen until i tap screen or on button again...

is there a way to hide UI bar after few seconds ?

I tried some solutions :

```
void volumeUp(){
    final AudioManager myAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    myAudioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
}
```

This show UI bar but it doesn't desapear until i tap screen

```
   void volumeUp(){
    final AudioManager myAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    myAudioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE,
            AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
}
```

same result

```
  void volumeUp(){
    final AudioManager myAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    myAudioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, 0);
}
```

this doesn't show UI

I didn't find other solution....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902892/how-to-programmatically-trigger-the-touch-event-in-android

Answer (score -1):

Add below code in your volumeUp(); method,

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AudioManager.setVisivibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }, 1500);
```

Comment: Android studio tell me :"Cannot resolve method 'setVisivibility' in 'AudioManager'" !